# Is it possible to automatically generate and populate tables in one schema based on tables present in another schema in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am fairly new to **PostgreSQL** and would like to know about possible **best practices** and whether it is **possible at all** to **automatically generate and populate tables in one schema based on tables present in another schema**, possibly using triggers and functions. My reason for doing this is that I have been told that it is preferable to do calculations within the database, compared to pulling the data, running calculations and inserting them again. I should mention that I am able to do the latter in **python** using **psycopg2**.

I understand that triggers and functions may be used for automatically populating columns based on other columns within the same table, but I have not yet been able to produce code that does what I would like, therefore I am seeking help & hints here. To clarify my question I would like to describe how my database looks right now:

A schema named `raw_data`, populated by an arbitrary and increasing number of tables related to measurements performed at different locations:

- `area1 (timestamp, value)`
- `area2 (timestamp, value)`
- `area3 (timestamp, value)`
- ...

Each table consists of two columns `timestamp` and `value`. New data is added continuously to each table. A table is created using the following code in python, using psycopg2 with an active connection `con` to the database:

```py
    table_name = schema_name + '.' + table_name.lower()
    sql = ('CREATE TABLE ' + table_name + ' ('
           'timestamp varchar (19) PRIMARY KEY, '
           'value numeric (5,2) NOT NULL, '
           ');')
    try:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql)
        con.commit()
    except psycopog2.Error as e:
        con.rollback()
        print(e)
    finally:
        cur.close()
```

My aim is to do a "live" (performed as soon as new values are inserted in a table in the `raw_data` schema) analysis (calculations) on the data that is available in each table in the `raw_data` schema, but it is also my interest to not alter the tables in `raw_data`, as I later on plan to run multiple "live" analyses with different methods, all based on the data in the tables in `raw_data`. Therefore, I would like to make a schema (named `method1`) that automatically generates tables inside itself, based on tables present in the `raw_data` schema.

If possible I would also like for the new tables to be populated by a specified number of rows from the column `(timestamp)` as well as values that have been calculated from the `(value)` column in the `raw_data` table.

Is this even feasible or should stick with pulling the data, doing calculations and reinserting using python and psycopg2?

I would like to apologize in advance if I am unclear in my use of technical terms, as I have not received any formal training in SQL or python.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In particular what exactly do you mean "live". Also what happens when the number of rows (values) exceeds 14400? How are tables created in the source schema (raw-data)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have read through both pages and tried to adhere as much as I could to the guidelines there. I have also updated my question to hopefully answer your questions :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new table using:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html

A generic example below:

```
CREATE TABLE AS 
   another_schema.new_table 
SELECT ... FROM 
    some_schema.existing_table 
WHERE
    specify conditions
LIMIT
    14400
```

Not sure if applies here but there is a SAMPLING method for pulling out data:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html

TABLESAMPLE sampling_method ( argument [, ...] ) [ REPEATABLE ( seed ) ]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do know how to make a table and specify the column datatypes. Would you perhaps be able to assist me in constructing the sql-code that would create a schema that automatically copies parts of tables that are already present in another schema?

Comment: A schema can't do that.  There are [EVENT TRIGGERS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/event-trigger-definition.html) that can be run on creation of a table. That could also work on creation of a schema. Personally I would do that as you open yourself to possible errors and incomplete results. Better to write a Python script that does that with proper EXCEPTION handling.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'll stick with doing the calculations in python then! :-)